# master_api.py exists, but rosmaster cannot locate it

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosmaster, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run roscore, i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore", line 36, in <module>
    from rosmaster.master_api import NUM_WORKERS
ImportError: No module named master_api
```

According to a post regarding the same [error](https://answers.ros.org/question/316120/importerror-no-module-named-rosmastermaster_api/), I did this:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
$ ls -al /opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May 22 10:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 138 root root 12288 May 22 10:16 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1707 Aug  7  2018 exceptions.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   450 Mar 19 02:55 exceptions.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1698 Aug  7  2018 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   275 Mar 19 02:55 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  5411 Aug  7  2018 main.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4032 Mar 19 02:55 main.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 37116 Aug  7  2018 master_api.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 33746 Mar 19 02:55 master_api.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3102 Aug  7  2018 master.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2133 Mar 19 02:55 master.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 14319 Aug  7  2018 paramserver.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 10630 Mar 19 02:55 paramserver.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 18575 Aug  7  2018 registrations.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 17901 Mar 19 02:55 registrations.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8050 Aug  7  2018 threadpool.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  6688 Mar 19 02:55 threadpool.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3159 Aug  7  2018 util.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1907 Mar 19 02:55 util.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8427 Aug  7  2018 validators.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8646 Mar 19 02:55 validators.pyc
```

master_api.py exists, so why can't rosmaster locate it? is there a fix to this problem, like changing some path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323705/master_api.py-exists,-but-rosmaster-cannot-locate-it/) by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem with my Kinetic on Ubuntu 16 after a recent upgrade/dist-upgrade. A work around is to rename or move roscore to something else.

```
sudo cp /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/bin/roscore /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/bin/roscore1
```

Hope this help until a better solution is found.

Edit 1: I had the issue fixed by reinstalling the rosmaster package.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ros-$ROS_DISTRO-rosmaster
```

---

Originally posted by [vunguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/41752/vunguyen/) with karma: 31 on 2019-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on 2019-05-27**:
Thank you. Although I found that roslaunch works just fine, even though it starts another instance of roscore.